# How to create the temporary directory in the localhost system using golang

Tags: go, path, directory

Here I'm trying to create a temporary directory in my local system using the below mentioned code

Code

```
path := "/home/iron/go/"
fmt.Println(os.Stat(path))
// this statement prints the data showing numbers
if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    os.MkdirAll(path, 0755)
}
```

I also searched for it but I want to do this from above code or add some lines to code.

Links for making temporary directory:- [link 1](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/d065806656c81021527069f3877fa762), [link 2](https://ispycode.com/GO/Files-And-Directories/Create-A-Temporary-Directory)

Comment: Are you trying to create a directory with the specific path "/home/iron/go/" or are you trying to create a temporary directory with an arbitrary path? If the former, call os.MkdirAll as in the question. If the latter, call [ioutil.TempDir](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempDir).

Comment: yeah I used it but it will create the folder `361911691` using this number but I don't need this numbers. Is there any way to solve this? @thunderCat trying to create the directory using specific path

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: the problem is that when the temporary folder is created then it will join this number with the given name. Is there any way that these will remove from the folder name?

Comment: The code in the question does not do what you are describing. Please post your actual code.  The goal of ioutil.TempDir is to create a new directory. The function appends text to the prefix to ensure that the directory is unique.  If you want to create a directory with a known name in [os.TempDir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#TempDir), then `os.Mkdirall(filelpath.Join(os.TempDir(), "yourpath"))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just get the **os temp** directory and manually create a folder under this directory without **random** suffix(random is for solving conflict):

```
goPath := filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), "/home/iron/go/")
> /var/folders/m2/4clpt6wj62j6dt9kwpr4b5fh0000gn/T/home/iron/go
```